# Controlling Media Players with C#

Tags: c#, windows, media-player, multimedia

I need to write an application in C# which controls different media players. My MediaKeyboard can control for example Songbird and WMP so there must be some kind of Interface that both players implement, or am I wrong?
How would I write this kind of application?

Comment: So what I did in the end was: I used the mediakeyboard keys to control different applications. The functionality is very limited, but play,pause,stop... works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Songbird has a developer center, explaining how to program the API. [Click here](http://getsongbird.com/developers/). Generally, you will find that each application will have it's own API, and they will have to be programmed individually.